# fetch data from mysql then display via JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to fetch data from mysql, and echo it by a `json_encode`. then my `JQUERY` will catch `JSON` via `$.getJSON` and append the result into my `<ul>`.

im trying to figure out why the data being captured by JQUERY is not printing on my index.php

this is my `index.php`

```
<html>
<?php 

    include_once('connect.php');

    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM data";
    $query  = mysql_query($sql);
    $result = array(); 


    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))  
        array_push($result,                  
            array(                          
            'name' => $row[1],              
            'msg' => $row[2]));

    echo json_encode(array("key" => $result));      
?>

<body>

<ul>
    //insert fetch data here
</ul>



<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my JQUERY

```
function my_function() {
     $.getJSON("index.php", function(data) {
       $.each(data.key, function(){
       $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+this['name']+"</li>"
                      "<li>message: "+this['msg']+ "</li>");
       });
 });
}
```

Comment: If you want a php script to return json, then the json string must be the **only** thing `echo`d by the script. You have a bunch of html which makes for invalid json.

Comment: Do you have the srctag in the index.php aswell? If so, that's your problem, make it only return the json array. If not, please update the post to what you have

Comment: can you expand more about what you mean of 'must be the only thing echod by the script'

Comment: first to see that it returns JSON use an `alert(data);`. And is better to use separate php files, one for the JSON result and one for the page you want to display the `ul`.

Comment: `<html><body>{"foo":"bar"}</body></html>` IS NOT valid json. `{"foo":"bar"}` IS valid json.

Answer (score 0):

**first**: check your index.php output by itself to see if it's displaying valid json. ¿Are there invalid UTF8 characters? In that case json_encode's output is null.

**second**: I'd use plain ajax method hinting json as dataType:

```
jQuery.ajax({
       url: 'index.php',
       dataType: 'json'
}).done(function(data) {
    for (i=1;i<data.length;i++) {
        datarow=data[i];
            $("ul").append("<li>Name: "+datarow.name+"</li>");
            $("ul").append("<li>message: "+datarow.msg+ "</li>");
        }

       });
```

**third**: don't use the same script to generate the json and to display it, it makes no sense to decouple view from app if you do it all in the front. In that case you might as well use plain php to generate it all, as the previous answer told. (@Abdoul Sy)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to fetch your data via JSON as you're echo-ing the JSON on the same page.
you could do something like this:

```
<ul id="jsonData" data-json-data="<?php echo json_encode($result;)?>"
```

And in your js file:

```
var myData = $('#jsonData').data('json-data');
```